# How do I create a IE Add-On in .NET?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, add-on

If somebody may knows a blog posting with a basic example, that would help a lot.

Google search gives me mostly links to add-in-express.com.

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, don't. Just don't.

Details are at [Create a shell extension ...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1428326d-7950-42b4-ad94-8e962124043e/)

since IE and Explorer are the same component with a different skin, you will run into the same kind of troubles.

Comment: Yep, if there are at least 2 extensions targeting different versions of .NET, one of them is gonna win, the other one lose, because only one version of CLR can be loaded into IE process.

Comment: On the second thought: the reason for "don't write" is that the host process is not expecting CLR to be injected. I don't know whether IE already loads CLR by himself, because of all this xbap stuff etc...

Comment: Already loaded CLR would also eliminate race conditions, since the incompatible extension will just not load.

Comment: There is always the possibility to write the injected part of extension in C++ and spawn a new .NET process to do the work. This of course depends on the nature of the extension and the "work".

Answer (score 2):

You can check this url:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx

it deals with making an extension for Windows Explorer but I know that for IE it works very similar.

It is the library that for example qttabbar uses:

http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/

(as I say, it can be adapted to IE).