# internet explorer add-on in .net

Tags: internet-explorer, add-on

Is there a way to create add-on for IE in .NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352217/how-do-i-create-a-ie-add-on-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not recommended.